# Laravel права доступа

Tags: laravel

Народ, добрый день!
Нужен совет с правами, суть примерно такая:
Есть компании, внутри каждой компании свой список ролей и пользователей.
Авторизовать права на функционал мы можем через токен `->middleware('ability:users-update')`.
Но, кроме этого нужно еще авторизовать принадлежность редактируемого пользователя к данной компании, что-то вроде

```
public function update(User $user){
    if(request()->user()->company_id != $user->company_id) return abort(403);
}
```

Такое себе писать в каждом методе... Нужен способ получше) Подскажете?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать web middleware где вы "до перехода в методы" определяете компанию и подставляете нужную реализацию некого сервиса в апп контейнер.

Comment: Да, в middleware я могу определить к какой компании принадлежит пользователь, который вызывает метод, но я не знаю какую модель он дергает, роли - это как пример, но это могут быть любые, связанные с этой компанией сущности, клиенты, роли, пользователи, события, новости и т.д., но мы точно знаем, что в любой из них есть company_id для проверки

Comment: Все всегда что-то дергают) поясните простым примером. Пользователь заходит на сайт и вы хотите часть данных от него "спрятать" или "запретить" в зависимости от id компании?

Comment: Вот полная суть: Создается компания, внутри нее есть свои роли, пользователи, клиенты и т.д. Соответственно их можно редактировать, если у пользователя достаточно на это прав. И вот конкретный пример стандартный запрос на редактирование: put /api/users/123, put /api/clients/321, put api/posts/4124 мы должны всякий раз проверять принадлежат ли id'шники 123, 321, 4124 к той же компании, к которой и пользователь, вызвавший эти методы